# Accessing standard call ringtones in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to access (ie. list) and then play standard ringtones through the iPhone SDK?  I've had a good search through the SDK but can't find anything obvious.

Note I'm not talking about changing ringtones - just being able to have the user select a standard ringtone and then play it from an application via the audio service.

Comment: well, you can overwrite the existing ringtones via ssh - but no renaming is possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's totally weird, but the System Sounds API in Core Audio doesn't give you access to the default or user-installed ringtones, nor does anything else.