# Is it possible to get the file list of all ringtones that install in iPhone

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get the file list of all ring tones that install in iPhone?
I mean only get the the file name list rather than access the ring tone files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently access user-installed ringtones, or the default system sounds.

Comment: You can make it vibrate, that's about it (if its an iphone) and not a ipod touch or ipad.

Comment: Is it possible check if a ring tone is in iPhone searching by its name? such as 'myringtone.m4r'

Comment: No it's not. Your application runs in a sandbox and won't be able to scan folders outside it's sandbox.

Comment: but it looks like I can access or browse the ringtones folder in /Library/Ringtones  as said in threads below

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717545/how-to-access-the-iphone-library-folder-programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389373/accessing-standard-call-ringtones-in-iphone-sdk

Comment: that user (masterb) has rep 1 so I don't think he is very much reliable. also he is mentioning that he is not sure ringtones can be played if the device is not jail break. I am very much sure that you can't access the iPhone system folders